# Chart testing with WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, charts, webdriver

Unable to find correct xpath or id to interact with chart elements using WebDriver. Please help!
Chart example: http://icharts.net/chartchannel/evolution-du-smic-dans-les-pays-de-lue_m3lxyc9ac .

I haven't tested anything like that before. 
Please help me with a real working example on how to click on one of the circles (for example orange circle next to "Bulgarie" text) with an explanation how to find the xpath or identifier recognizable by WebDriver.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two important things you need to handle and take into account to test a this dynamic page:

- there are `iframe` elements on the page and the chart itself is inside a nested `iframe`. If a desired element is inside an `iframe`, you'll have to [switch into its context](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames).
- the chart is quite dynamic - you'll need to use [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) extensively

Working example (in Python) that prints all of the items in the legend:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://icharts.net/chartchannel/evolution-du-smic-dans-les-pays-de-lue_m3lxyc9ac")

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.container iframe"))
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

# wait for the chart to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.legendSeriesContainer .seriesNameBox")))

# get all the legends
for legend in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.legendSeriesContainer .seriesNameBox"):
    print(legend.text)

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
Bulgarie
République tchèque
Estonie
Irlande
Grèce
France
Croatie
Lettonie
Lituanie
Luxembourg
Hongrie
Malte
Pays-Bas
Pologne
Portugal
Roumanie
Slovénie
Espagne
Royaume-Uni
Slovaquie
Belgique
```